# How to bypass the server authentication in Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I know that bypassing the server authentication like this is no more can be done on chrome:

```
https://admin:$ecure@wop@example.com
```

Please suggest me any other to bypass the server authentication.

I tried to use switch.toalert but its not working because untill i enter the credentials the page keeps unending loading

```
URL = https://admin:$ecure@wop@example.com

driver = new ChromeDriver();
        System.out.println(driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to(ReadPropertyFile.loadURL("URL"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with Chrome options this should work.

```
String URL = "https://admin:$ecure@wop@example.com";
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Path of the chrome driver");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("start-maximized");
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.navigate().to(URL);
```

Please let me know if this working for you.